# Debugging Stuck Ruby Process - Workling\Starling

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, centos5, workling

We have a rails app that about every 24 hours runs the load average on the machine well beyond 5. It looks like a stuck Ruby process specifically related to a background process running to manage event and calendar reminders. It seems like killing it and restarting the app resolves temporarily:

```
dd   6554     1  0 00:38 ?        00:00:15 /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/starling -d -p 15151 -P /u/apps/dd/shared/starling.pid -q /u/apps/dd/shared/starling -L /u/apps/dd/shared/starling.log
```

Is there anything better than debugging with GDB?  I don't see much useful info there.

- Ruby 1.8.7 x86_64
- Rails 2.3.9
- Eventmachine 1.0.3
- Workling 0.4.9.9
- Starling 0.10.1
- CentOS 5.9

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything you listed is super old.  You're problem could be as simple as memory leaks that have been fixed in the years since all of those versions were released.

Otherwise, you could try out some Ruby profile tools such as [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof).

Comment: Yes, needs to upgraded but it ran fine for a year or more. This just started. I was able to dig this out of the workling logs:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `real_connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) (Mysql::Error)
  from /u/apps/dd/current/vendor/plugins/workling/script/../lib/workling/remote/invokers/threaded_poller.rb:37:in `join'

Wokklings losing connection after a time out?

Possibly a MySQL config issue?

Comment: Could be.  You could check to see if MySQL is holding on to connections too long and therefore getting to the point where they all get used up.